# Check if string contains in array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string, contains

When I use a hard coded "4" in the second if, it works. But I have a dynamic string[] ProfileArray and want to check, if the value of View08ListBox1Item contains/not contains with one of the strings in ProfileArray. Why it does not work, when I change the "4" against the string[] ProfileArray?

global:

```
static string[] ProfileArray;


case "Profile":
            foreach (ListItem View08ListBox1Item in View08ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (View08ListBox1Item.Selected)
                {
                    if (!View08ListBox1Item.Value.ToString().Contains("4"))
                    {
                        //:do something
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //:do something
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
```

this was my first idea, but it does not work:

```
case "Profile":
            foreach (ListItem View08ListBox1Item in View08ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (View08ListBox1Item.Selected)
                {
                    if (!View08ListBox1Item.Value.ToString().Contains(ProfileArray))
                    {
                        //:do something
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //:do something
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
```

Comment: A string cannot contain an array.. its the other way around.

Comment: Look at the datatype for the argument in `Contains`: it wants a `string`. An array of strings is not the same thing as a plain-old string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ProfileArray is an array not a string.

```
ProfileArray.Any(x => x == View08ListBox1Item.Value.ToString())
```

I think this can work.

In .NET 2.0 you can use

```
Array.IndexOf(ProfileArray, View08ListBox1Item.Value.ToString()) == -1
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: For strings it might be better to explore the StringComparison enumerator `x=>x.Equals(View08ListBox1Item.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.*)`. Better control over how you want to match, I find that not very often do I care about case in strings.

Comment: @kelton52 sure, but it depends a lot on the type of info

Comment: That's true, just wanted to toss out a nuget of info.

Answer (score 6):

you can use Linq

```
ProfileArray.Any(x => x == View08ListBoxItem.Value.ToString())  //Contains
!ProfileArray.Any(x => x == View08ListBoxItem.Value.ToString()) //doesn't contain
```

non linq extension

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this T[] array, T value) where T : class
{
   foreach(var s in array)
   {
      if(s == value)
      {
         return true;
      }

   }
  return false;
}
ProfileArray.Contains(View08ListBoxItem.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: or ProfileArray.All(x=>x == View08ListBoxItem.Value.ToString()) // doesn't contain

Comment: @ManuelFischer - Added an extension method that you can use

Answer (score 1):

A string cannot contain an array.. its the other way around.

You could use non-linq way too `ProfileArray.Contains(View08ListBox1Item.Value.ToString())`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
    bool found = false;
    for ( int i=0; i < ProfileArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (View08ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString().Contains(ProfileArray[i])
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

No need to iterate the listbox either as shown.